# vim mapping for editing vimrc not working?

Tags: vim

Trying to do the following in .vimrc:

```
" Define map leader
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

" Fast editing of the .vimrc
map <leader>e :e! ~/.vimrc<cr>
```

(From http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html)

but whenever I run the command by trying to type `:,e` I get this error message:

```
E481: No range allowed
```

I'm new to vim (currently running through the Nettuts video series) and this is driving me nuts... what am I doing wrong? I've quit and relaunched vim several times, no change.

I've also tried (out of the video tutorials) this:

```
nmap ,ev :tabedit $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

... which gives me this: `E492: Not an editor command: ,ev`

The command does show up when I run `:map`:

```
n  ,ev           :tabedit $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Help!

Comment: There is no need to have both `let mapleader=` and `let g:mapleader=`. Leave only the latter, first is exactly the same statement (unless you are running it in the function where it is equal to `let l:mapleader=`). And do use `nore` before any `map` command: `noremap`, `nnoremap`. You will thank me for suggesting this once you will want to do something like `noremap : ;`+`noremap ; :`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type `,e` instead of `:,e`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple. *butts head against wall*

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as an ex `:` command, you may use `cmap` instead of `map`.  See `:help cmap`

```
" Should work:
cmap <leader>e e! ~/.vimrc<cr>
```

But as you've defined it, you should be able to run it with simply `,e`

Answer (score 0):

I use:

`nmap <silent> ,ev :e $MYVIMRC<CR>`

you can also adjust that mapping with `:so $MYVIMRC<CR>` so that it sources your vimrc without having to quit Vim for changes to take effect (you obviously have to use something other than ,ev).

Comment: It is not impossible to make `,ev` launch `:so $MYVIMRC` instead of `:e $MYVIMRC` in case you are already editing it.